# Heavy Boolean Operations

Tags: add-on, performance

I was wondering why boolean operations are hard to compute for pc, ı got one desktop and one laptop , and uses 2 different operating system , but in all systems stiuation is the same.
I am using boxcutter addon , jmesh addon , fluent addon but all same , Cpu gets higher than 100% percentage.

Why this is so heavy computation for pc, and my systems are one with ryzen 5 1600 and radeon rx580 gpu , the other 5th gen i5 and gt740 gpu , same result , even in cycles rendering i am happy with my computer performance , but in simple cutting addon , computer go nuts , is there anyone with the same problem ?

 **problem is same for all addons and for boolean modifier too**

Comment: it can take time on some meshes. can you provide a sample? yours might have a bad modifier order or mesh is too complex to begin with.

Comment: I am sorry but i cant providing a video now.It looks like i think when systems being linux and amd together , those addons have really bad performance.(Well its same on windows too but nevermind ) .İ guess hardsurface modelling is a dream for me i guess. Even when sculpting 4m vertex my pc wont even lag.But in those addons , drives me nuts.Really badly written addons , from code quality perspective i mean , i guess they dont control thread counts and it makes cpu go nuts.(The most usable of them is jmesh adddon fyi )

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think most of them use blender python api so it's not their fault and they use what blender provides. And boolean by itself is a heavy operation (last time I used 3ds max boolean I had to wait 15 sec and it was almost instant in blender.)
If you provide more info on your problem (maybe a sample) I could help you better.